# How do I symbolicate a crash report of a Mac OS X app that a user emailed to me?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, debugging

I am working on an app that I have sent to a few beta testers. Within just a few minutes of launching the app a user got a crash. When the window poped up saying the app had crashed he copied all of the text in the details section and emailed it to me. I have saved the text into a plain text file and given it the .crash extension which causes it to be opened by console like a regular crash report so I think I have the extension right (but maybe not).
The version I sent out was built by Xcode with the Archive option so Xcode knows where the app and .dSYM are.
I know that with iPhone apps you can drag a crash report to the organizer and Xcode will symbolicate it for you. I can not find anywhere that will take a Mac crash report.
I have looked at `atos` but it talks about memory locations including the location the app was running at and I don't see that information listed in the report I have. Looking at the raw crash report it looks like a view controller was released early but I can't really tell if that was the cause or a symptom.
My real question is; is there a way to have Xcode symbolicate the report or a tool that I can just hand over the .dSYM file, app, and report and get back a symbolicated report?
I've looked all over Google but everything I find (other than the previously mentioned man pages for `atos`) is about symbolicating iPhone reports, not Mac OS X ones.

Comment: What is "symbolicate"? Or should I ask that on english.stackexchange.com ??

Comment: "Symbolicate" is when you add the debugger symbols that you stripped out for a release build back in. You have to have the .dSYM file for the exact build the crash came from to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or as in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354072/317461

Put your release build and your .dSYM file in the same directory and open terminal

```
$cd directory
$lldb MyApp.app
(lldb) image lookup -v --address 0x00085f3c
```

Comment: I was looking so long for a good answer on this question. Now just submitted two bugreports to Apple: 
1) Add a .crash file to Xcode > Devices > Library > Device Logs > Import as it's possible for iOS
2) make atos run for .app with space in the name

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with our app and I was symbolicating the crash reports manually line by line with `atos`.

I now tweaked Apple's symbolicate script such that it works with Mac apps and crash reports from PLCrashReporter.

https://github.com/lksnmnn/Symbolicate-CrashReports

**How to use it:**

Make sure you have all of the following files on your computer:

1. The crash report: *report.crash*
2. The dSYM file of your app: *MyApp.dSYM*
3. The executable / app folder of your app: *MyApp.app*
4. The improved symbolicate script: *symbolicatecrash*

Now go in the command line (Terminal) and do the following:

```
# set the developer directory
export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

# Now run the script
/Path/To/symbolicatecrash /Path/To/report.crash > /Path/To/readable_report.crash

# Use -v for verbose logging.
```

The script will find your dSYM and your executable and symbolicates as much as it cans. You will now find your symbolicated report in the stated output file *readable_report.crash*

**Build settings:**

For proper reports and symbols, set your build settings to this:

```
Strip Debug Symbols During Copy: Yes
Strip Style: All Symbols
Strip Linked Product: Yes
```

*Edit: Improved the answer such that it aligns with the Stack Overflow answer policy.*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11421416)

Comment: @AtheistP3ace The link doesn't answer the question. It's a link to a library that the answerer used to solve the problem. This provides a solution to the question *is there a way to have Xcode symbolicate the report or a tool that I can just hand over the .dSYM file, app, and report and get back a symbolicated report?* and this provides a way.

Comment: If it doesn't answer the question it shouldn't be an answer. If it does answer the question but doesn't include the relevant parts directly in the answer it shouldn't be an answer.

Comment: Thank you @AtheistP3ace for clarifying the StackOverflow policy. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Zizouz212  Should I add the complete script to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDB for Symbolication, Put your release build and your .dSYM file in the same directory
open terminal

```
$ cd directory
$ gdb MyApp.app
(gdb) info line *0x00085f3c
```