# xcode 5 not importing .crash file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash, xcode5, symbolicate

I have an OSX app that is constantly crashing on one device.

I have setup the project build setting to never strip symbols (debug or release):
[image: Symbols setting]

When I build the app, I copy both it and the .DSYM files to a local folder. I then copy the app to the testing computer, where I launch it. After it crashes, I copy the generated .crash file (found via the Console app), to my local folder which also contains the app and .DSYM file.

In XCode, I switch to the Organizer window, choose import and select my .crash file.

Nothing happens. My understanding is that this should symbolicate my crash report, so that I can understand it better.

Any suggestions as to that i'm doing wrong? (Or if I don't have a proper understanding of how to symbolicate a crash log)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found the answer:

[How do I symbolicate a crash report of a Mac OS X app that a user emailed to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085734/how-do-i-symbolicate-a-crash-report-of-a-mac-os-x-app-that-a-user-emailed-to-me)

That basically, XCode does not support symbolicating osx crash reports.